# Android Progressbar not displaying on dark background

Tags: android

I have a photo gallery that displays photos in a ViewPager.

The detail layout has a dark background and includes a ProgressBar that I hide when the image is fully downloaded. Works fine on my Nexus Android 4.4.

On an HTC Desire Android 2.2, the ProgressBar can't be seen against the dark background, although if I set the background of the ProgressBar itself to white, I can see that it displays and hides correctly. It also displays fine in other layouts where the background is white.

How do I get the ProgressBar to appear against a dark background for 2.2?

Here's my layouts;

photo_detail_pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

photo_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try 
         `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"`. While the default is supposed to show up on dark backgrounds and inverse is for light backgrounds, api level 10 and under might treat it differently.  Also your theme might be affecting the color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems like it was some kind of conflict with the theme.

I have android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" for the application.

I set the theme for my photo gallery activity to android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

In the Fragment, force the ProgressBar to the front:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_detail, container, false);

    loader = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loader);
    loader.bringToFront();

    // other stuff...
}
```

And in the Activity, explicitly set the ActionBar background to dark to get rid of the holo blue line:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo_detail_pager);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ab_solid_dark_holo));

    // other stuff...
}
```